# Opera Emulator localhost

Tags: asp.net, emulation, opera, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm developing an asp.net web application for mobile devices (Visual Studio 2013) and I need an emulator for testing (will run on Windows Mobile 6.5 scanners so the WebMatrix iPhone and Windows Phone 7 are not very helpful). I downloaded the Opera Mobile Emulator and it looks very promising for what I need except that I cannot get connected to my localhost. I am very new at this so please forgive me if this has a simple answer. If I use the URL http://localhost:52285/frmChooseDB.aspx I get "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized". If I replace localhost:52285 with my IP address (I work remotely so my vpn connection has 2 IP Addresses, 1 for client and 1 for server so I'm using the client IP Address but not sure this is the IP Address I should be using) I get "HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode." I've tried using 10.0.2.2 instead of my client IP address and get "The page cannot be displayed"

How can I get the emulator to connect to my localhost page? Or if anyone knows of a way I can use the emulators I already have in my Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK with Visual Studio 2013, I'd love to hear how.

Thanks.